# Why exiting "using" invokes unexpected Dispose()?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, idisposable, using-statement

Here is my case:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("A Dispose"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void Dispose(){ Console.WriteLine("B Dispose"); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (B b = new B())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Final output is "A Dispose".
I've read some documents which introduce the difference of override and new, and something telling that "using" substantially equals to "try-finally". But I am still can't get answer to why it is not B::Dispose got automatically invoked.
Comparingly following's output is "B Dispose"

```
B b = new B();
try
{
}
finally
{
    b.Dispose();
}
```

Please help, which did I miss.

Comment: _[Implement the dispose pattern for a derived class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class)_, MSDN

Comment: What is surprising? You have `new` not `override`, so `B` is not implementing the `IDisposable.Dispose`. Putting it another way, you cannot do `new` with explicit implementation `new void IDisposable.Dispose(){ Console.WriteLine("B Dispose"); }` is not valid

Comment: `new` is essentially "I want to reuse a name my base class has used". If you had used any other name for that method you wouldn't have had to use `new` and it would be far more obvious it bears no relation to the base class' method of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1214-the-using-statement), for a reference type:

```
using (ResourceType resource = «expression» ) «statement»
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    ResourceType resource = «expression»;
    try {
        «statement»;
    }
    finally {
        IDisposable d = (IDisposable)resource;
        if (d != null) d.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the resource is first cast to `IDisposable`, which means that `A`'s `Dispose` is the one called, since `B`'s `Dispose` is merely hiding it instead of overriding it.

If you want to correctly implement `IDisposable` in a class hierarchy, [see the best practices for this in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class).

Comment: If the implementation of the finally was simply `resource.Dispose()` and not `((IDisposable)resource).Dispose()`, then `B`'s `Dispose` would be the one called, because it is hiding `A`'s `Dispose`. This is not what's happening here, and OP is asking why.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I'll clarify that part.